# Debug Log In subscriber org (managed package) not working

Tags: managed-package, isv, subscriber, debug, debug-logs

I am logged in to the subscriber org through LMA (subscribers)... and I still just get do detail in the log.

Supposedly we should see full detail when logged in through LMA. I do recall this working a year ago, but for a while now this is all I get.. Has something changed? How do I get full access now?

[image]

Comment: https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/211007/cant-see-managed-package-code-logs-when-logged-into-subscriber-org-with-lma    https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/166246/access-to-debug-logs-in-managed-package   Check this once

Comment: Thanks ... That post made a point about the session. Whilst I am using the same user account. I am interacting with salesforce via API. I think that is the issue.. but still dont know if there is a workaround?